# Keep private field type

Tags: typescript

I have a somewhat strange case where I need a class property merely to hold on to a generic type and not because I want to access it at runtime.

I have a class and utility type like this:

```js
class Foo<T> {
    private _dummy!: T;
}

type UnwrapFoo<T extends Foo<any>> = T extends Foo<infer Unwrapped> ? Unwrapped : never;
```

The property `_dummy` is never accessed in any way, but it is required for `UnwrapFoo` to work. Otherwise, were it not present, `T` would be discarded meaning that `UnwrapFoo` can not infer it anymore.

My issue is that, when TypeScript generates the respective `.d.ts` file, it erases the type of `_dummy`, as it is a private property. The generated typings look like this:

```js
class Foo<T> {
    private _dummy;
}
```

Now, `T` is being discarded again and `UnwrapFoo` ceases to work. Is there a good way to keep the type of `_dummy`? I could make it public, but I do not like that because it is purely an internal property that should never be accessed by a user of the `Foo` class (also, it is always `undefined` anyway, despite what its type says).

Comment: TS intentionally doesn't annotate private fields in declaration emit and there's no way around that. Make it `protected` instead?  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Is all that you're wanting from the `UnwrapFoo` utility is to be able to infer the Type of type parameter T? If so, then it's not really required for it to work, check [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYlqdm)

Comment: @0xts relying on non-structural type inference is fragile, see [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnBDqN) for example.

Comment: @jcalz Your first suggestion works, making the property `protected` is good enough for my use case.

Comment: Note that in my answer I used [the `declare` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) instead of `!`, since depending on your compiler options, `!` might still end up emitting the property to runtime, which I assume you want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be well-documented, but the types of [`private` class properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private) are intentionally suppressed from `.d.ts` files generated via [the `--declaration` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration), and there's no way to change that. In terms of official documentation, I only see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37621#issuecomment-608039158) in a related GitHub issue, and the fact that the [declaration emitter source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/83f3abda153f0f567e296a3c75cdca37c7eb065d/src/compiler/transformers/declarations.ts#L777-L779) actively suppresses type annotation for `private` things except in constructor [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties).

Assuming you need to keep a dummy field for this purpose and you don't want it accessible from the outside in general, you might consider changing it to a [`protected` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#protected) instead:

```
// foo.ts
class Foo<T> {
    declare protected _dummy: T;
}

// foo.d.ts
declare class Foo<T> {
    protected _dummy: T;
}
```

This isn't *as* private as `private`, since someone could come along and [subclass it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#extends-clauses), but at least people won't be tempted to access that member on an instance.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gWAFDQOgBMBTUMAJxOgAcL4AXMpo6AfSIFcBbbgTwBc0FAG48AXzx4GfGtQCqAOwDuFMDQTIU0EgA8miojE1IwivmgwBePIWE79JQ8cRIAlooBmJCtCWr1OSIMAH4-FTUaIOghRRIANx8xXDwgA)

Answer (score 0):

So in general keep in mind that types in TypeScript do not generate and JavaScript code, they are metadata only for you and the compiler to know about as you write code.  Because of this, types cannot be saved to variables.

---

Regarding the generation of the `.d.ts` files, keep in mind that the type is not present because the property is `private`.  Nothing outside the class can access it, so putting a type on it for a type definition file is useless.  Consider the following:

```ts
class Foo {
    private _dummy: string = '';
}
```

The generated `.d.ts` file is as follows:

```ts
declare class Foo {
    private _dummy;
}
```

However, a `public` property **will** have type information since other things that use the `.d.ts` file will have access to a `public` property.

```ts
class Foo {
    public _dummy: string = '';
}
```

The generated `.d.ts` file is as follows:

```ts
declare class Foo {
    _dummy: string;
}
```